# How can I solve and/or approximate an equation with the variable in the limit of the integral

Tags: integration, analysis, integral-equations

I would like to solve the following equation for $x$:

$$\int_{0}^{x}\frac{p\frac{(2(n-x)+1)^t}{(2(n-x)+2)^x}}{p\frac{(2(n-x)+1)^t}{(2(n-x)+2)^x}+(1-p)\frac{((n-x)+1)^t}{((n-x)+2)^x}}\left[\frac{(2(n-x)+1)^t}{(2(n-x)+2)^x}-\frac{((n-x)+1)^t}{((n-x)+2)^x}\right]\left[\frac{\Gamma(1+x)}{\Gamma(1+t)\Gamma(1+x-t)}\right]dt=K$$

Is there any way I can get an expression for $x$?

Is there any approximation I can do to get a simpler expression?

All tips are much appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Having a quick look at the expressions, there are some that do not depend on $t$ in the integral. Hence these can be taken outside, leaving a simpler integral